# (Django) How do I set limit_choices_to another class from where the ManyToManyField points to?

Tags: django, django-models

I currently have three classes `User`, `UserProfile`, and `Vendor`. `User` is the built-in Django one from `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`. The other two are as follow

Here is `UserProfile`

```
class UserProfile( models.Model ) :
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ( 't', 'tenant'           ),
        ( 'm', 'property manager' ),
        ( 'o', 'property owner'   ),
        ( 'v', 'vendor'           ),
        ( 'w', 'web user'         ),
        ( 'x', 'other'            ),
    )
    user      = models.ForeignKey( User, unique = True )
    user_type = models.CharField( max_length = 1, choices = TYPE_CHOICES, default = 't' )

User.profile = property( lambda u : UserProfile.objects.get_or_create( user = u )[ 0 ] )
```

And here is `Vendor`

```
class Vendor( models.Model ) :
    def __unicode__( self ) :
        return self.name

    name  = models.CharField( max_length = 135 )
    users = models.ManyToManyField( User, null = True, blank = True )
```

I want to limit the Vendor.users to only `User` whose `UserProfile.user_type` is `vendor`.

How do I use [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to). Can I do something like...

```
users = models.ManyToManyField( User, null = True, blank = True, limit_choices_to = { UserProfile.objects.filter( user = self.users ).user_type : 'm' } )
```

I know the above code will throw an error, but hopefully you can see what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried limit_choices_to = {'profile__user_type' : 'm'} ? That would better fit how limit_choices_to works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it with

```
manager = models.ForeignKey( User, related_name = 'manager', limit_choices_to = { 'userprofile__user_type' : 2 } )
```

where 2 is the primary key (`user_type_id`) of property manager in the `UserType` class.